# Deployment Java web application in cloud

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, deployment, spring-security, cloud

I have a question about deployment Java application in cloud.
I've developed simple application in Java usign JSP, Spring security and MySql.
I need to deploy it in Cloud and show others just for several days. 
I want to find some FREE hosting that will allow me to deploy application and configure database.
First I thought about Google Apps Engine but I read that there are some issues connecting with MySQl.
Can anybody advise me anything? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should take a look at  Dotcloud for free-temporary hosting.

Comment: thank you! but i've found another hosting that suits more Cloudfoundry